# Is my Kolsch still a Kolsch if I used the wrong yeast?

Tags: yeast

I followed Jamil's Kolsch recipe to the letter but pitched WLP 833 into my carboy thinking it was a Kolsch yeast. I found out that it's actually a different German yeast strain. Will this still be a good Kolsch or do I have to call it something else now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a homebrewer.  You can call it whatever you want.  Will it taste like a kolsch?  Might not have some of the soft bread notes that WLP029 (Kolsch/German Ale).

I am sure you have a very nice helles bock on your hands potentially.  If you fermentation was spot on I am sure its great on way or another.

I am sure some brewing purists would tell you that even if you pitched WLP029 it still wouldn't be a kolsch because it wasn't brewed in Cologne Germany.

Answer (score 2):

If it tastes like a kolsch, it is a kolsch.  Well, technically is only REALLY a kolsch if it's brewed in Koln, but what the hey.  Using 833, though, it won't really taste like a kolsch.